# getting 404 with Handlebars.js tmpl files Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, handlebars.js

I am new to Tomcat and using Handlebars.js. I am making a prototype page to test working with handlebars.js. I have installed a vanilla version of Tomcat 7 running on Windows 7. I have added my page its related js css and image files and put them in the webapps folder inside a MyApp folder.

so we have

```
 |
 -- webapps
      |
      -- MyApp
           |
           -- index.html
           |
           -- css/
           |
           -- img/ - all my sprites are here
           |
           -- js/ - contails all my vendor and prsonal js files
           |
           -- tmpl/ contains all my handlebars template (*.tmpl) files
```

When I load the page the index file loads, the js, css and image files are getting accessed. However the tmpl file is getting a 404 error

> HTTP Status 404 - /MyApp/tmpl/MainView.tmpl
>
> type Status report
>
> message /MyApp/tmpl/MainView.tmpl
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Any thoughts? I have already added the tmpl mimetype as plain text.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Are you deploying this as a web archive (MyApp.war file) or just putting your files in there?

Comment: no just have the exposed index.html inside the MyApp folder. Just doing a rapid prototype. Some other things I found out. If I move a css file in to the tmpl folder I can see that. So the issue is something with the .tmpl files. So I renamed the files to .txt and still getting the 404.

Comment: Check the permissions on all the files. Possibly tomcat can't see the .tmpl files due to file permissions.

Comment: @Gus I have gone through set all to full control and turned off read only. I then restarted Tomcat through services. When I view index.html, I get a 404 error. When I look a the network tab in firebug I show all files upstream loaded properly. Only the mainview.tmpl fails to load and hence the rest of the app fails to load. Also here is my content of mainView.tmpl. <script id="tmpl-MainView" type="text/html">
  <div class="MainView">
    <header id="MainViewHeader"></header>
    <section id="MainViewWorkspace"></section>
    <footer id="MainViewFooter"></footer>
  </div>
</script>